# How to create a notification when my app receive a broadcast message

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

My app simply receives a broadcast from another app. I am new to broadcast receiver so I am facing problems. 
I want that when my app receive a broadcast message then in the notification panel a notification appears.
I tried a lot but find nothing on the internet.

I tried youtube videos and StackOverflow but I found nothing.

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "EBR triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

// The following code doesn't work. I copy this from StackOverflow//
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent, 0);

```
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setTicker("Ticker text");
    builder.setContentTitle("Content of Notification");
    builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");  
    builder.setNumber(100);
    builder.build();

    // add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());


}


}
```

No errors and I was expected that there will be a notification icon appears when broadcast receives but nothing happened.

Comment: I don't really know what i'm talking about but i'll post it anyway because you haven't gotten any answers yet. ;-) 1: Did you declare the broadcast receiver in the manifest? 2: Did you create a notification channel? Also, you shouldn't call builder.build() twice.

Comment: I did both of the things. by the way I'll did paste here twice the builder method by mistake

Comment: Thanks! I remove that line and know it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of broadcast receiving.

**App 1 (sender)**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("MY_NOTIFICATION");
intent.setComponent(
    new ComponentName("com.example.stackoverflow", "com.example.stackoverflow.MyReceiver")
);
intent.putExtra("data","Notice me senpai!");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**App 2 (receiver)**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="MY_NOTIFICATION"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MyReceiver.java:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
        Toast.makeText(context, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", "name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("description");
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL_ID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("textTitle")
                .setContentText(data)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
```

Please note that there are [Broacast limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) since Android 8. So you need to to provide the explicit class for handling i.e setComponent param along with action

Comment: As I am new to this area please tell me how will I handle the setComponent param explicitly.